# Switch views on the same tab in a tab bar WITHOUT using a navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiview

I am looking for a way to switch the current view in a tab container to another, all within the same tab and ***not using*** a navigation controller.

I have tried something like this:

```
FooViewController *fooViewController = [[FooViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FooViewController" bundle:nil];
self.view.window.rootViewController.view.window.rootViewController = fooViewController;
[fooViewController release];
```

And this:

```
FooViewController *fooViewController = [[FooViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FooViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:fooViewController.view];
[fooViewController release];
```

To no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: In your second example, is `self` the root view controller or some other view controller?

Comment: When I run the second example, it looks like `self` is the actual view container of the active tab, and `.view` ends up being the active view.  I think this is the case because the code actually removes the view from the container and leaves the tabBar in tack, but it does not replace the view with the new one.

Comment: Well it doesn't replace it because `[self.view addSubview:..]` adds it as a subview of the view *which you just removed from the screen*. You'll have to swap out subviews of some common superview. However I'm not sure (given your code) what the proper way to do this is.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if the second approach is even the right approach, so I agree that removing that view from the superview and trying to add something in its place is counterintuitive.

Comment: No, I think that's exactly what you should do, but that's not what you're doing. In the code you posted, you are removing the view from the screen, then putting your new view inside it, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The method I used was to create a subclass of UIViewController that I used as the root view of 3 child view controllers.  Notable properties of the root controller were:

- viewControllers - an NSArray of view controllers that I switched between
- selectedIndex - index of the selected view controller that was set to 0 on viewLoad.  This is nonatomic, so when the setSelectedIndex was called it did all the logic to put that child view controller in place.
- selectedViewController - a readonly property so that other classes could determine what was currently being shown

In the setSelectedIndex method you need to use logic similar to:

```
[self addChildViewController: selectedViewController];
[[self view] addSubview: [selectedViewController view]];
[[self view] setNeedsDisplay];
```

This worked really well, but because I wanted to use a single navigation controller for the entire application, I decided to use a different approach.

I forgot to mention you will want to clear child view controllers every time you add one, so that you don't stack up a ton of them and waste memory.  Before the block above call:

```
for (UIViewController *viewController in [self childViewControllers])
    [viewController removeFromParentViewController];
```